# How to call methods with varargs in RJava with zero values?

Tags: rjava

I am working on a package that uses RJava for identifier mapping (in biology): [BridgeDbR](https://github.com/BiGCAT-UM/bridgedb-r). One of the methods calls a Java method which has vargs, mapID():

```
xref <- .jnew("org/bridgedb/Xref", identifier, datasource)
datatarget <- getDataSource(code=target)
targets = .jarray(c(datatarget), contents.class="org/bridgedb/DataSource")
```

Here the getDataSource() method returns a Java object of type org.bridgedb.[DataSource](https://github.com/bridgedb/BridgeDb/blob/master/org.bridgedb/src/org/bridgedb/DataSource.java).

The actual call of interest is then made like, where (as shown above) xref and targets are Java object, and where mapper is also Java object, see below:

```
mappings = mapper$mapID(xref, targets)
```

This mapper object is an instance of the [IDMapper](https://github.com/bridgedb/BridgeDb/blob/master/org.bridgedb/src/org/bridgedb/IDMapper.java) interface and defines the mapID() method using vargs:

```
public Set<Xref> mapID (Xref ref, DataSource... tgtDataSources)
  throws IDMapperException;
```

Now, I want to call this method without data sources. In Java I would just do:

```
someMapper.mapID(someXref)
```

... and Java find this method.

However, I cannot figure out how to do this in RJava. The following variants all do not work (e.g. .jarray(c(), contents.class="org/bridgedb/DataSource") return NULL):

```
mappings = mapper$mapID(xref, c())
mappings = mapper$mapID(xref)
mappings = mapper$mapID(xref, NULL)
mappings = mapper$mapID(xref, .jarray(c(), contents.class="org/bridgedb/DataSource"))
```

The output of .jmethods(mapper, name="mapID") is:

```
[1] "public java.util.Set org.bridgedb.rdb.SimpleGdbImplCommon.mapID(org.bridgedb.Xref,org.bridgedb.DataSource[]) throws org.bridgedb.IDMapperException"
[2] "public java.util.Map org.bridgedb.rdb.IDMapperRdb.mapID(java.util.Collection,org.bridgedb.DataSource[]) throws org.bridgedb.IDMapperException"
```

How can I call this Java method (mapper$mapID) with RJava with just the xref?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/jarray.html, you should supply a list in the call to `.jarray`, possibly with a single `NULL` element

Comment: Yeah, that worked out fine:.jarray(list(), contents.class="org/bridgedb/DataSource"))